# How to show the digits which were repeated in c?

Tags: c

The question is that show the digits which were repeated in C.

So I wrote this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

int main(void){

    bool number[10] = { false };
    int digit;
    long n;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);

    printf("Repeated digit(s): ");

    while (n > 0)
    {
        digit = n % 10;
        if (number[digit] == true)
        {
            printf("%d ", digit);
        }
        number[digit] = true;
        n /= 10;
    }

      return 0;
}
```

But it will show the repeated digits again and again
(ex. input: 55544 output: 455)

I revised it:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int number[10] = { 0 };
    int digit;
    long n;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);

    printf("Repeated digit(s): ");

    while (n > 0)
    {
        digit = n % 10;
        if (number[digit] == 1)
        {
            printf("%d ", digit);
            number[digit] = 2;
        }
        else if (number[digit] == 2)
            break;
        else number[digit] = 1;

        n /= 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works!

However, I want to know how to do if I need to use boolean (true false), or some more efficient way?

Comment: Your second version doesn't "work", try it with `1122333`.

Comment: You can print digits in seperate loop. or fix your second silution

Comment: ok!.I understood why it can't work!!Thanks! : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your first version work, you'll need to keep track of two things:

- Have you already seen this digit? (To detect duplicates)
- Have you already printed it out? (To only output duplicates once)

So something like:

```
bool seen[10] = { false };
bool output[10] = { false };

// [...]

  digit = ...;
  if (seen[digit]) {
    if (output[digit])) {
      // duplicate, but we already printed it
    } else {
      // need to print it and set output to true
    }
  } else {
    // set seen to true
  }
```

(Once you've got that working, you can simplify the `if`s. Only one is needed if you combine the two tests.)

Your second version is nearly there, but too complex. All you need to do is:

- Add one to the counter for that digit every time you see it
- Print the number only if the counter is exactly two.

```
digit = ...;
counter[digit]++;
if (counter[digit] == 2) {
  // this is the second time we see this digit
  // so print it out
}
n = ...;
```

Side benefit is that you get the count for each digit at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed teaching and edit!
I think i can revise it like that :
<pre><code>if (seen[digit] && !output[digit])
  {
   output[digit] = true; printf("%d ", digit);
  }
  else seen[digit] = true;  <pre><code>

as you said that use only one "if".: )

Comment: You can't do code formatting in comment except with `` `backticks` ``, and that's single-line only.

Answer (score 1):

Your second version code is not correct. You should yourself figured it out where are you wrong.  You can try the below code to print the repeated elements.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

int number[10] = { 0 };
int digit;
long n;

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%ld", &n);

printf("Repeated digit(s): ");

while (n > 0)
{
    digit = n % 10;
    if (number[digit] > 0)
    {
        number[digit]++;;
    }
    else if (number[digit] ==0 )
         number[digit] = 1;

    n /= 10;
}

int i=0; 
for(;i<10; i++){
  if(number[i]>0)
       printf("%d ", i);
}
return 0;
}
```

In case you want to print the repeated element using `bool` array (first version) then it will print the elements `number of times elements occur-1` times and in reverse order because you are detaching the digits from the end of number , as you are seeing in your first version code output. In case you want to print only once then you have to use `int` array as in above code.

Comment: Because I break it when number[digit] == 2 ! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably much easier to handle all the input as strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char str[256] = { 0 };                      /* string to read                   */
    char rep[256] = { 0 };                      /* string to hold repeated digits   */
    int ri = 0;                                 /* repeated digit index             */
    char *p = str;                              /* pointer to use with str          */

    printf ("\nEnter a number: ");
    scanf ("%[^\n]s", str);

    while (*p)                                  /* for every character in string    */
    {
        if (*(p + 1) && strchr (p + 1, *p))     /* test if remaining chars match    */
            if (!strchr(rep, *p))               /* test if already marked as dup    */
                rep[ri++] = *p;                 /* if not add it to string          */
        p++;                                    /* increment pointer to next char   */
    }

    printf ("\n  Repeated digit(s): %s\n\n", rep);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** you can also add a further test to limit to digits only with `if (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9')`

**output:**

```
$./bin/dupdigits

Enter a number: 1112223334566

  Repeated digit(s): 1236
```

Comment: I think I will learn it in the future.
Now ,I can't understand you code a lot .Q_Q
But thanks for your answer.

Comment: It just takes what the user entered an puts the whole thing in `str`, then uses a pointer `p` to look at each character in `str` and uses `strchr` (which just tests if the digit (a character) pointed to by 'p' occurs again in the input. If so, it checks the `rep` (repeat) string and asks the same thing. Is this digit already in `rep`? If not, it adds the repeated char to the `rep` string. After the `while` loop finishes testing each character, it just prints the `rep` repeat string out. Basically the same as you are doing, this just relies on `strchr` to do the testing :)

Comment: Ok!I realize some parts.= )
Thanks you explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

Error is here

if (number[digit] == true)

should be

if (number[digit] == false)

Eclipse + CDT plugin + stepping debug  - help you next time

Comment: That will print all the number's digits, not repeated digits.

Comment: @Mat: This is not totally wrong. __Maxx__, just failed to tell, that after making these changes, one has to add this statement as well `number[digit] = true` inside this `if` clause.

Comment: @nIcEcOw: If you print a digit the first time you set `number[digit]` to true, you'll be printing all the digits. Try the code out if you want, with just the modification above. (The setting of `number[digit]` is already done.)

Comment: @Mat: Ahha, now I got the idea, what the actual question is about, my bad. Previously I thought, that if `11233` is one input, then output should be `123`, but it seems like the OP wants only those numbers to be outputted, that are repeating, not those which are appearing only once. My bad, I just understood the real question, just now :-) But Thankyou, for bringing this to my knowledge :-)

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has given the solution: You can achieve this using the `counting sort` [see here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/). Time complexity of solution will be `O(n)` and space complexity will be `O(n+k)` where `k` is the range in number.

However you can achieve the same by taking the `XOR` operation of each element with other and in case you got `a XOR b` as zero then its means the repeated number. But, the time complexity will be: `O(n^2)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
main()
{
   int num[SIZE] = {2,1,5,4,7,1,4,2,8,0};
   int i=0, j=0;
   for (i=0; i< SIZE; i++ ){
       for (j=i+1; j< SIZE; j++){
            if((num[i]^num[j]) == 0){
                printf("Repeated element: %d\n", num[i]);
                break;
            }
       }
   }
}
```